# Apollo GraphQL variable Query

Tags: reactjs, react-native, graphql, apollo, react-apollo

After much reading Apollo React documentation I am unable to create a GraphQL query using a Redux provided props variable `displayLocation` of the `DiscoveryList` component. Flow type of `displayLocation` given below: -

```
type DisplayLocation = {
  lat: number,
  lng: number,
};
```

I am getting the following error: - `Variable lat of type Float! was provided invalid value`, surprisingly the provided value to the float variable is `37.33233141`. Redux and Apollo Component integration code given below :-

```
export default compose(
  connect(({ displayLocation }) => ({ displayLocation }), {
    updateDisplayLocation,
  }),
  graphql(
    gql`
    query DiscoveryList($lat: Float!, $lng: Float!) {
      destinations(radius: {
        latitude: $lat,
        longitude: $lng,
        distance: 10000})
        { name
          id
          country_code
        }
      }`,
    {
      options: ({ displayLocation }) => ({
        variables: {
          lat: displayLocation.lat,
          lng: displayLocation.lng,
        },
      }),
    },
  ),
)(DiscoverList);
```

Many thanks for your help.

I was also wondering to feed redux props into the Apollo GraphQL query, should we `connect()` redux first and then Apollo `graphql()` or the other way around before exporting the component please?

Comment: this looks correct - can you check in your store to see the current value of displayLocation?

Comment: The `displayLocation` in my store is correct even the `this.prop.data.variables` object is correct, it shows 2 json fields lat, lng with correct float values but still i get the 'invalid value to Float error'.

Comment: what if you don't use ! / the variable maybe a double?? try to coerce to float.    query DiscoveryList($lat: Float, $lng: Float)

Comment: GraphQL doesnt have double, JS doesnt have either :)

Comment: I would strongly suggest to store these values as strings, and only convert them to floats at the point of use, because of the inaccuracies of the base 64 system. In my experience I generally wrap components in graphql then I wrap them in Redux. I think there is a case for both approaches.

Answer (score -1):

Define like that:

```
type DisplayLocation = {
  lat: Float,
  lng: Float,
}
```

See more graph.

Comment: Please add more details to your answer [How to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: just change number to Float